# idk what to do?? error:warning: implicit declaration of functi

Tags: c

```
Solution.c: In function ‘main’:
Solution.c:22:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘print’; did you mean ‘lrint’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     print("%i\n",i+i1);
     ^~~~~
     lrint
/usr/bin/ld: ./cc0yYuu0.o: in function `main':
/tmp/submission/20201211/17/06/hackerrank-ce7baf859a8c0733a8f6cf6e64968568/code/Solution.c:22: undefined reference to `print'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/submission/20201211/17/06/hackerrank-ce7baf859a8c0733a8f6cf6e64968568/code/Solution.c:24: undefined reference to `print'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/submission/20201211/17/06/hackerrank-ce7baf859a8c0733a8f6cf6e64968568/code/Solution.c:26: undefined reference to `print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You probably mis-spelled `printf` in your code.

Comment: look at this line _Solution.c:22_ for the above comment or share code

Comment: Double check your code for functions that are miss spelled or for which there is no prototype.  I.e. Missing header file.

Comment: print might need to be printf ?  Or you left out #include <strings.h>

Answer (score 2):

Use the method printf() instead of print(). That may give a solution to your problem